# Android DataBinding Activity finish()

Tags: android, android-activity, mvvm, data-binding, android-databinding

I am trying to implement MVVM in my app with DataBinding library. For simple tasks that I have accomplish I can find the way out, but problem is that I cannot finish activity after some action.

Problem:

After receiving specific broadcast I have to close activity from ViewModel class. Since VM class doesn't have reference of the View, how can I finish the activity?
To be precise, I have splash screen and corresponding VM class for it that starts IntentService for downloading a data. After the data has been downloaded I have to finish the splash screen and start MainActivity. I have found the way to start new Activity from VM, but to finish the previous one is the mystery.

Can you please help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Create a SplashStatus model with a ObservableBoolean:

```
private static class SplashStatus {
   public final ObservableBoolean isFinished = new ObservableBooelan();
}
```

Here is your Splash layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
       <variable name="status" type="com.example.SplashStatus"/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Splash Screen"
           android:onFinish="@{status.isFinished}"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And binding adapter method:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:onFinish")
public static void finishSplash(View view, boolean isFinished) {

   if(isFinished){
       ((Activity)(view.getContext())).startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class))
       ((Activity)(view.getContext())).finish();
   }
}
```

In the `SplashActivity.java` init your data binding on onCreate. Whenever you assign `isFinished.set(true)` onFinished method will start your MainActivity and finish current.

Answer (score 5):

if you want just to finish() the activity from layout with databinding:

`android:onClick="@{(view)->((Activity)(view.getContext())).finish()}"`

Answer (score 0):

if the databinding owner is fragment, may choose another method

At first, define your ViewModel class

```
public static class ViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public ViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public void onFinish(View v) {
        ((DialogFragment) DataBindingUtil.findBinding(v).getLifecycleOwner()).dismissAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

then in your databinding layout

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.xxxx.settingitemmoretest.MainActivity.ViewModel" />

</data>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:onClick="@{viewModel::onFinish}"/>

</FrameLayout>
```